# Tensorflow Session hangs after creating tf.Session()

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess=tf.Session()
```

The code hangs after this. Installed tensorflow with version 0.9 and GPU support (cuda-7.5).

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please open an issue on the [TensorFlow GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues). If possible, try running Python under `gdb` and print the hanging thread's stack backtrace.

Comment: I ran into this once, but the issue disappeared after rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

I spent 2 days trying various solutions found online. Eventually, this fixed my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-drivers
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem too.
For me, the problem is caused by installing incompatible GPU device driver on my Ubuntu system.
My Ubuntu version is 14.04, but I installed device driver for Ubuntu 15.x. So everytime it hangs on starting tensorflow Session.

Finally solved this problem by re-installing correct GPU device driver for Ubuntu 14.04.